# Current activity context in controller for paper trail Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

As per the docs, we can set any meta attribute to our versions table as per this:

Where text_description is my custom attribute.

```
class ApplicationController
 def info_for_paper_trail
  { text_description: request.port }
 end
end
```

However, all I can get in this method is the current `request object` from `ActionDispatch::Request` class.

I want to set the `text_description` with a custom string which will contain a detailed text regarding the activity, usually with the attribute changes and it's associated data.

I know that `changeset` instance method provides me with all the details of the specific activity, how can I get the same in the controller to set my custom attribute?

Comment: Please see docs section [4.c. Storing Metadata](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata).